# 50000 checkboxes in aspx/html too heavy -any alternative?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, checkbox, infragistics

Requirement is to have 50000 checkboxes in an aspx page .
Currently I have implemented it in aspx , the page is slow and the selection is very slow, at times the application hangs. The load is too much.
 Currently the page size is 10 mb I need to reduce that too.

I am looking for an alternative approach like jquery or something keeping in mind that I will need to use checkboxes.

Things I have tried which didn't help the cause:

- ASPX list box
- Html div- checkbox
- Infragistics
- Iframe.

Would appreciate any answer.

Comment: Could you not setup paging through the checkboxes? Or categorise them in to separate pages, or search for them by keywords?

Comment: 50000 checkboxes? I hope this is an exercise...

Comment: Just wondering, what could be the purpose of getting 50000 checkboxes on one page?

Comment: o_O and I think you will have problems with browser

Comment: not really an option, there are other controls on the page. Right now these checkboxes are generated dynamically based on the no. of records from database.

Comment: Downvoted, because you have not given a specific reason this is required.  Displaying to a using this number of checkboxes is completely unacceptable from a user experience point of view.

Comment: no it aint an excercise. :P i wish it was.

Comment: @user2040600 But you should paginate your data, whatever you are trying to do

Comment: _"the load is too much"_..and that was a `machine`....I wonder what a user would suffer....you should probably think about changing your approach because your question is already telling you to....

Comment: let me guess, a grid of check boxes?

Comment: wait, are you using the html <input type="checkbox"> or the asp:checkbox? I can see the webforms approach will be super slow if you have post back events. the input style will be down to the browser

Comment: ya I know that its not advisable to use so many checkboxes but that is not under my control, I am not the sole owner of the application. I have been asked to do the following in short time, so if there is any good jquery plugin that supports large data or something similar , that would be of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to select the checkboxes using code in your code behind, that's going to be slow because it's a back-end solution for what should happen in the front-end. Even if you set up pagination so you display only 50 checkboxes at a time, it'll still be slow if you're doing the checking in the code behind. To select checkboxes with jQuery, which is a much faster solution, try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#body').on('click', 'input[type=submit]#uxSelectAll', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("checked");
        var isChecked = $(this).hasClass("checked");
        $('input[type=submit]#uxSelectAll').val(isChecked ? "Unselect All" :  "Select All");
        $(this).prev().find(":checkbox").prop("checked", isChecked);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Here you have a Select All button that checks and unchecks the checkboxes on click. You can select the checkboxes with a selector like this:

```
$(this).find(":checkbox").prop("checked", true);
```

Note: This question assumes that you're using  as your checkboxes.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if you are rendering 50k checkboxes/rows I'd suggest there's some refactoring that could be done on the design? Maybe you could consider higher level groupings of rows, and have a fewer number of checkboxes update a collection of related entities/rows?

But if you do need to the 50k checkboxes, you may want to consider pagination to separate them into pages of reasonable amounts.

So, as you said you're using an aspx page, I'll assume it's a web forms application. If that's the case, you can use the GridView control to manage the pagination for you (examples at http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/ctrlref/data/gridview.aspx, there is also a paging example at that link).